# Oracle Get two variables returned from select query inside of a package

Tags: oracle

I modified the procedure to make it smaller but I really only want to run the select query once.  This will reduce the cost of running the procedure.  How can I get the `prevContectID` and `nextContentID` without running the query twice.  This is replacing a previous procedure so I do not want to change the `IN` and `OUT` so I do not have to find every where it is being called.

```
procedure getSeq(theContentID IN table.contentID%type,
                 prevContentID OUT table.contentID%type, 
                 nextContentID OUT table.contentID%type)
BEGIN

  SELECT myPrev into prevContentID, myNext into nextContentID
    from myTable
   where contentID=theContentID;
  RETURN;
END getSeq;
```

Comment: Where is there two runs? I only see one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shown procedure most likely doesn't compile. The correct syntax for SELECT ... INTO using several variables is:

```
SELECT myPrev, myNext INTO prevContentID, nextContentID
from myTable
where contentID = theContentID;
```

Comment: I thought it might be something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a cursor to fetch the values from `myTable`.For your approach you need to do proper exception handling ,when `theContentID` does not exists in myTable,because that will give you `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

```
PROCEDURE getSeq (theContentID    IN     table.contentID%TYPE,
                  prevContentID      OUT table.contentID%TYPE,
                  nextContentID      OUT table.contentID%TYPE)
IS
   CURSOR getcontentID_cur
   IS
      SELECT myPrev, myNext
        FROM myTable
       WHERE contentID = theContentID;
BEGIN
   OPEN getcontentID_cur;

   FETCH getcontentID_cur
   INTO prevContentID, nextContentID;

   CLOSE getcontentID_cur;
END getSeq;
```

Comment: theContentID will always exist because I shortened the code and I validate the contentID before I run the select.  I didn't want to put more code than was needed to get the answer. Codo gave me what I needed.

Comment: @NathanStanford:what are your parameters of more code?.First you validate by scanning your `myTable`,for the contentId. Secondly you fetch the code for prev and next id .It means your whole process will scan your table twice .With my approach you can do it once .Nyways just suggesting the pros /cons of your approach .Thanks

Comment: Sorry it is more complicated then just as the code says.  I have it running less then 15 ms most of the time.  So I am good for now.  Thanks for the concern.  Due to someone doing a cursor and getting everything and looping through it to get the next and prev is why we rewrote the code.  We are now using the Lag(), Lead() to get prev and Next.  Also when Null we are getting the First_Value() and then the Last_Value() to allow a previous next to loop to the beginning or to the end of the list.